# What does this dash mark in a DIP 4-bit counter IC indicate?

Tags: integrated-circuit, counter, dip

[image: IC Package]

I have seen a dash mark in 74LS193 4-bit counter IC while working with it in a project. What does this dash mark indicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a Texas Instruments part and according to their [Environmentally Friendly Solutions Guide](http://focus.ti.com/pdfs/logic/Environmentally_Friendly_Solutions.pdf) that part of the marking has the following meaning as per the JEDEC specs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It means that the device conforms to JEDEC JESD97 E-Category specification for
Pb-free and reduced environmentally unfriendly substances (in this case E4 category).